# HTML CSS: Change the Bootstrap Tooltip Shape

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, popover

Right now the Bootstrap tooltip looks like this, How do I remove the cartoon bottom triangle, and make it just a regular rectangle?

**Currently:**

[image]

**Goal:**

[image]

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tooltip&stacked=h

**Original Code:**

```
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: none` to `.tooltip .arrow`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

```css
.tooltip .arrow  {
  display: none!important;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">Top</a>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Hooray!">Right</a>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help